# $.post() Get url of php in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making an html script that will use jQuery.post() method in order to use a php script. The post() method needs an url of the php code but my php code is part of the html code

 What Url should i use?

```
<html>

<body> 

<button onclick="test()">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var test = function() {
    $('--I DONT KNOW--',{testvar:"hello"});
}

</script>

<?php

$testvar = $_POST['testvar'];
echo $testvar;

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is a manual for this you know. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score 1):

An empty URL is a relative URL that resolves as the URL of the current page.

```
$.post("", {testvar:"hello"});
```

(Keep in mind that since your PHP does nothing with the data except output it, and your JS does nothing with the response, this will have no visible effect outside of the Network tab of your browser's developer tools).